# Custom Bootstrap 3 Table

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

just trying to create a custom table from bootstrap 3. I'm a bit of a amateur but have been trying for a while and can't seem to get it. I require a table, where each row contains two rows with a different amount of columns. Is this possible?

So each entry requires two rows; the top row requires 4 columns, and the bottom row requires 3 columns.  Is it possible to set the widths of each of these columns? Or is this too complex?

Thanks.

Comment: Please show what you have tried so far.

Comment: What do you mean "Bootstrap 3 Table"? Do you mean an html table or do you mean using the Bootstrap grid structure?

Answer (score 3):

The answer for your question is the Bootstrap documentation. You can use grids to create your custom layout.
 http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid

Otherwise basic tables with custom width of  will be your solution and this is **EASY**. Look at the below code. This generate table like this

[image]

http://getbootstrap.com/css/#tables

```
 <table class="table table-bordered">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>#</th>
      <th>First Name</th>
      <th>Last Name</th>
      <th>Username</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="2">1</td>
      <td>Mark</td>
      <td>Otto</td>
      <td>@mdo</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Mark</td>
      <td>Otto</td>
      <td>@TwBootstrap</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>Jacob</td>
      <td>Thornton</td>
      <td>@fat</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3</td>
      <td colspan="2">Larry the Bird</td>
      <td>@twitter</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: We appreciate it but once you get this working post the answer here for someone else to be benefited.

Answer (score 0):

You can as well use [Appizy](http://appizy.com/en/toolbox) to generate your layout starting from a spreadsheet. You just have to organise your content in an Excel file and then convert it in HTML with the online software. Check the examples.

Hope that can help. Nicolas

Answer (score 0):

`rowspan="#"` and `colspan"#"` will do what you're looking for, with or without Bootstrap.

**See this example: http://www.bootply.com/rwrPSj9VqW**

Also worth noting, your cells do have to be aligned (at least with a `<table>` they do) - i.e. to have 3 and 4 columns, one columns has to take up 2 spans, and the remaining 2 columns will be equal to the ones above.